# HTTP POST and GET using cURL in linux

Tags: command-line, scripts, https

I had server application in asp.net in windows in that i had a web service for that .

how can i call web service in ubuntu using shell script by using cURL command

Answer (score 124):

Linux provides a nice little command which makes our lives a lot easier.

**GET:**

*with JSON:*

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://hostname/resource
```

*with XML:*

```
curl -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X GET http://hostname/resource
```

**POST:**

*For posting data:*

```
curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://hostname/resource
```

*For file upload:*

```
curl --form "fileupload=@filename.txt" http://hostname/resource
```

*RESTful HTTP Post:*

```
curl -X POST -d @filename http://hostname/resource
```

*For logging into a site (auth):*

```
curl -d "username=admin&password=admin&submit=Login" --dump-header headers http://localhost/Login
curl -L -b headers http://localhost/
```

Comment: Can you see who's the author of http://stackoverflow.com/a/14978657/1251660?

Comment: i prefer your original answer that you provided the link to.

Comment: the `-H` flag can also be used to delcare your content as "application/json" when posting data with  `-X POST`